# Using CSS class causes problems

Tags: html, css

I set up my `.nav` *class* for my nav menu but when I use it it seems to cause problems and when I remove `.nav` and leave just `ul li` it fixes it but that also has a margin problem.

the problem is on the bottom I commented /*Problem*/
http://jsbin.com/fupewijame/1/

You must remove .nav

```
.nav ul li{
    width: 100%;
}
```

and change it to

```
ul li{
    width: 100%;
}
```

that kinda fixes it but you can see a margin error. I also must use `.nav` *class* as I don't want it global. Please help I can't see the bug

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
.nav ul li{
width: 100%;
}
```

use:

```
.nav li{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

if you don't want to have a margin

```
.nav{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but there is still a margin error? also any reason why that works?

Comment: you mean you don't want to have margin between you list items??

Comment: I mean the margin on the side and top of the list. I want it connecting and aligned with the show menu bar

Comment: I can't do it that way because the way I set it up I want my non responsive menu to be centered and your way makes it have my non responsive menu have no margin too. Its a little complex set up which is why I included the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you'd like it to look like with 100% width. If you give a little more information I can help further.

However, I noticed a few things that might be confusing your CSS.

1) The height is showing as "0" due to a float being applied to the list items. When you apply float to your items they are removed from the normal flow of the document.

To solve, try first removing this:

```
.nav li {
    float: left;
}
```

2) Most browsers add default padding and/or margin to ol and ul

I recommend you reset, and then try to style.

RESET:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

TARGET RE-STYLE:

```
.nav {
  margin: /* your style here */;
  padding: /* your style here */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
.nav ul li{
    width: 100%;
}
```

is saying :

- an element with class `.nav`
- with a descendant of type `ul`
- with a descendant of type `li`

Since `.nav` is a class of your `ul`, and not of an ancestor of your `ul`, you should use

```
ul.nav li {
   width: 100%;
}
```

that instead means :

- an element of type `ul` with class `.nav`
- with a descendant of type `li`

EDIT: for the margin problem, you should probably use `position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;`, that should not be used if not completely aware of how it works